# dynamically trigger the selected index change for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a simple dropdown with a method attached to it .. i want to trigger the selectedindex change event of that dropdown from code

```
<select id="ddStartPeriod" onchange="javascript:fnSetStartDate()">
<option value="RC">RC</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You mean `$('#ddStartPeriod').change()`?

Comment: try to avoid using inline JavaScript whenever possible.

Comment: yes i want the change event but it seems that it doesnot fire the event(fnSetStartDate()) associated with it ...

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the inline javascript and add an event trigger:

```
$('#ddStartPeriod').on('change', function(){
    alert('changed to '+$(this).val());
});
```

trigger from a button:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
     $('#ddStartPeriod').change();
});
```

Comment: i agree with the solution that u gave .. but my question is still how will i trigger the change event say on click of a button?

Comment: That is another question, but what do you want to trigger on a click of a button? If you click a button that is another event.

Comment: Like this: `$('#button').on('click', function(){ $('#ddStartPeriod').change(); });` ?

Comment: love you man. 
calling the .change() from a button for dropdown worked great for me.. 
Thanks.. :)